# Make domain purchased on dataflame resolve to Elastic Beanstalk application Pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application deployed via amazon Elastic Beanstalk, and a domain bought on dataflame.co.uk

Now, what I want to do is to make the domain name on dataflame resolve to my application on Elastic Beanstalk.

I figured out that there's two ways I can do that:

1 - create an hosted zone on Route 53 and a traffic policy that will resolve the DNS to my EB application, and then modifying the NAME SERVERS pointer on dataflame to make it point to the Route 53 ones.

Cost of the operation: 50$/month

2 - migrate the domain from dataflame to Route 53, this is what amazon suggests, but then I still don't know if there will be the need to create an hosted zone with traffic policies even in this scenario.

Can somebody enlighten me on that? or hint some alternatives to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route 53 contains 2 different services:

1. DNS resolution, and
2. Domain name registration

You can use both of these services, or one without the other. They are not dependent on each other.

#### DNS Resolution

If you want Route 53 to resolve your domain to your Elastic Beanstalk application, then you must create a hosted zone for it with appropriate record set entries.

Using Route 53, you could create CNAME records pointing to your EB app's endpoint. Or you could create an ALIAS record pointing to your EB app.

Costs for Route 53 DNS resolution is not $50 per month. The cost is $0.50 per hosted zone per month + traffic. See http://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/

Since dataflame also provides DNS resolution service, you could avoid Route 53 completely and use dataflame to resolve your domain name. To do this, you would create a CNAME entry in dataflame pointing to your EB app's endpoint.

#### Domain Registration

You can choose to transfer your domain from dataflame into Route 53, but this would be simply for registration purposes. You would pay for the transfer, then the annual domain cost (very similar to what you're paying at dataflame). If you do this, you still need to create a hosted zone.

If you want to keep your domain registration at dataflame, but you want to use Route 53 for DNS resolution, then you would edit your domain registration (in dataflame) and set the domain name servers to be those listed in your Route 53 hosted zone.